# increase and decrease the input value by .25 on click of plus and minus button jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

This is the reference website https://ekaya.in/products/handwoven-wine-silk-fabric-4324

Here the quantity value increases by .25 every time we click on "+" icon, I am trying to achieve the same thing, but I am not able to show "+" and "-" icon, here is my code  `<input type="number" placeholder="1.0" step="0.5" min="0" max="10">` can someone please help

Answer (score 2):

You can using [`stepUp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/stepUp) to increase and [`stepDown()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/stepDown) to decrease the value like the following way:

```js
const inputEl = document.getElementById("qntyInput");

//attach click event handler to the parent
document.querySelector(".qnty-control").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  //check if minus button is clicked
  if (event.target.classList.contains("minus")) {
    //decrease
    inputEl.stepDown();
  } else if (event.target.classList.contains("plus")) {
    //increase if plus button is clicked
    inputEl.stepUp();
  }
});

inputEl.addEventListener("input", () => {
  //format the input to 2 decimal places
  inputEl.value = parseFloat(inputEl.value).toFixed(2);
});
```

```css
.qnty-control span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  user-select: none;
  font-style: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="qnty-control">
  <span class="minus">-</span>
  <input type="number" id="qntyInput" placeholder="1.0" step="0.25" min="0" max="10">
  <span class="plus">+</span>
</div>
```

Using jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //event handler for "+" button
  $(".plus").on("click", function() {
    const input = $("#qntyInput")[0];
    input.stepUp();
  });

  //event handler for "-" button
  $(".minus").on("click", function() {
    const input = $("#qntyInput")[0];
    input.stepDown();
  });

  //format the input value to 2 decimal places
  $("#qntyInput").on("input", function() {
    const value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $(this).val(value.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```css
.qnty-control span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  user-select: none;
  font-style: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="qnty-control">
  <span class="minus">-</span>
  <input type="number" id="qntyInput" placeholder="1.0" step="0.25" min="0" max="10">
  <span class="plus">+</span>
</div>
```